# Wordpress twenty fifteen theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

How can I change the size of the cover picture (the thumbnail I've attached) automatically resize and fit in the twenty fifteen theme?
I want to change the dimensions of the cover image container and change it to a square cover rather than the default rectangular, but I can't seem to find it.
The website address: http://www.filsoof.me

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your theme's css file add:

```
.post-thumbnail {
   width:/*width here*/ !important;
   height:/*height here*/ !important;
 }
```

Replacing the width here and height here comments with the desired width and height be sure to remove the *s and the /s

Comment: I've tried that already, but unfortunately it only makes the size of the image smaller and the cover image part seems to reduce its size proportionally. 
you can see the result right now as I've set height and width to 300px.

Comment: Whats the height and width you need

Comment: actually I want it to auto-fit

Comment: Then take the width of the container and put it as height and width @Farzan.

Comment: Take a look at your site now its totally devastating @Farzan

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, and I changed it via the wordpress function "set_post_thumbnail_size"

The usage is the follow:

```
 <?php set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

You can find all info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)

Comment: now my problem is the container itself shrinks with the thumbnail too, same thing only scales to a smaller size.